# How to add column at a certain position?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My code :

```
mDb.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + table_name + 
            " ADD COLUMN " + column_name + " text");
```

The column is added to last position :

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | NewAddedColumn6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Is it possible to add a column between `Column3` and `Column4`?

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | NewAddedColumn6 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: That's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (question about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem); describe what you are trying to achieve by doing this instead.

Comment: Consider rearranging column order on `SELECT` instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per the [SQLite > ALTER TABLE > ADD COLUMN](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) documentation:

> The ADD COLUMN syntax is used to add a new column to an existing
> table. The new column is always appended to the end of the list of
> existing columns.

Hence, the answer to your question is **NO**.

However, there is a workaround. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253879/767881).

Comment: why do you need to create a column between Column3 and Column4  (whatever it means) ?

Comment: though it's really late and probably nobody cares but here is the reason why I needed this. 
User can create dynamically tables and list/render them with all columns. If a user later on decides this table need one additional column it will get displayed at the last position. But maybe this information was much more useful if it was next to another column. 
This issue became even worse when you add new items/references into the table, the workflow was very inconveniently interrupted, scrolling up/down.
Last but not least same issue applied to the Excel export.

Comment: Position of a field might require only for display purposes. This can be easily be achieved by selecting specific columns in specific positions. `select * from emp` will result the default column position defined. Where as `select empno, empname, deptno, salary, etc from emp` will re-order the resulting column position, which would be very handy for *reporting* type of views. For `Excel` type of exports too explicit selection of columns will help to get your desired result.