# Add new database table column using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, sqlite, mobile

I am trying to create a mobile app using Jquery Mobile and is able to create a local database and tables to store some input. Now I am trying to use code to add new column in one of the table (for purpose of updating of the app and database scheme).
I tried to use 'ALTER TABLE' but got error and not able to add the column.

Question
- Is it possible to add new column using Jquery ?
- If not how should I update the database table scheme with the existing data still intact?

I tried using the below code which gave me 'undefined' error.

tx.executeSql('ALTER TABLE UserAccount ADD TimeZone NUMERIC NOT NULL;',            [], successCB, errorCB);

Appreciate your expertise.

Comment: this might help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253804/insert-new-column-into-table-in-sqlite

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have checked out and tried, but it give me 'undefined' error. And to note, i am using Jquery which the post may be used in Android.