# Approach uses ALTER TABLE to add new columnsin in sqlite. How to set the columns position in table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade, restore

Approach uses ALTER TABLE to add columns when backup and RESTORE a database file in android.
How to set new columns position in table.
The columns is showing as a last columns in table but i need this column in middle.

Comment: Why do you want your column in the middle? Just order the fields whenever you make a query. Or is there any other meaning for that feature?

Comment: No, my client define the table structure so can't change the order.

Comment: Can we use alter table and add new column in middle?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question and don't vandalize your old questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try different approaches to maintain the positioning of columns.

One way can be to 1) rename your table 2) create new table with correct column ordering 3) then insert all records from renamed table. This is mentioned on following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253879/867475

Another approach can be to add the column at the end and use [Views](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) to fetch columns in correct ordering. [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation

> The `ADD COLUMN` syntax is used to add a new column to an existing
>   table. The new column is always appended to the end of the list of
>   existing columns.

But, there is a work around way.
Read this [*answer on SO*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253879/767881).

**Refer to**:  [***SQLite: ALTER TABLE: ADD COLUMN***](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)