# What is wrong with this sqllite alter table query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite

I need to add column to table, for now I have this code:

```
public void InsertParameter(string ColumnName)
{
    string sql = "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD :value1";

    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql,conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value1", ColumnName);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But this give me syntax error:

> near ":value1":syntax error

I really can't figure out what is wrong with this query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert new column into table in sqlite ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253804/insert-new-column-into-table-in-sqlite)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but more of a follow-up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that the syntax for SQLite's [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) statement requires a column-name here instead of an arbitrary string-typed [expr](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html).  This means you can't use a bind-parameter with it.

(Apparently, the implementation of prepared statements requires the table and column names to be known at “compile” time, so it can't be a variable.)

If you need a C# function that dynamically selects a column name at runtime, you need to dynamically create the SQL statement with a hard-coded column name.  (Use double-quoting to prevent SQL injection attacks.)

```
string sql = "Alter Table table_name ADD "\"" + ColumnName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
```

Comment: I removed my answer since you posted yours from the comments :-)  This is much more clear and explains the approach.  Thank you for the useful info!