# How to I convert a sqlite command to a python-sqlite command

Tags: python, sqlite

How would I implement the following command in python:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN COLNew {type};
```

[Taken from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253804/insert-new-column-into-table-in-sqlite)

I assume it would look something like the following:

```
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN COLNEW ... ???
```

The problem is there are lots of sqlite tutorials for python and lots of sqlite examples. How does one convert a sqlite command to python?

Comment: Why is having a lot of available tutorials a problem? Did you work through any of them before asking?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? If you have a SQL query that works, then it should also work as `cursor.execute(<SQL query>)`. There's some stuff to learn about parameter substitution, but unless you describe exactly what you don't understand, we can't really help you any more than the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) or any tutorial could.

Comment: +1 Bryan, plus you don't give what kind of values you want to put in that column, which would help to choose the type for the column.