# Android - Need to create database based on JSON object received from API response

Tags: android, database, api, dynamic

I have an API from which I receive JSON object response, which is dynamic (meaning response JSON object contains different key-values time to time), so that the database for my Android application need to delete current table and create new table based on JSON keys.

For simple example, today I get JSON object response like

```
`{"name":"STRING", "age":"INTEGER"},
```

next week I will get response like

```
{"name":"STRING", "id":"INTEGER","Country":"STRING"}`
```

I checked Room and Realm, but the problem is that I can't able not get any clear examples or tutorials to make use of it.

FYI - I am new to Android database concept.

Edit #1:

What I need is to create DB Table columns based on JSON keys (i.e, by default table X has two columns A and B and receiving JSON object contains three keys A,B and C, so that DB need to include column C dynamically)

Comment: use shared pref for lightweight type, no need to use db.

Comment: I just gave a simple JSON example, but real DB need to store large data that's why I need to use Database instead of Shared Preferences.

Comment: so drop the table, create new schema table with columns as per the response

Comment: is it possible to do it programmatically, please mention how to achieve it in simple words

Comment: yes, are you new to sqlite?

Comment: yes, I saw examples about migrations but they we're all adding columns in Entity class and migrating DB to new version. My question is to do it dynamically without need to recode it every time while having new columns.

Comment: why don't use sql alter command to add new col, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253804/insert-new-column-into-table-in-sqlite

Comment: ok, I can able to create column using alter table for the database but how to dynamically add the column field in model class ?

Answer (score 0):

For storing values in Android Sqlite database
check his  https://androidjson.com/save-store-php-mysql-json-parsing-data-sqlite/

it will be helpful to you

Comment: its helpful to know how to load JSON object to database but the problem I'm facing is different. Thanks for the response bro.

Comment: let me know what you are facing

Comment: above link example will store data based on given JSON object values to already defined columns in DB table but what I need is to create Table columns based on JSON keys (i.e, by default table X has two columns A and B and receiving JSON object contains three keys A,B and C, so that DB need to include column C dynamically)