# android unique index comment

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, unique

I have an application where user needs to input data via edittext and it cant be duplicate, so i create unique index. But how to make the comment if unique index is met? So user knows what is the error.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DIFFERENT ON user(name, gender)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you are looking for a way to specify that a column is your primary key (so unique and not null)

ALTER TABLE user
ADD PRIMARY KEY (name)

**EDIT**
I noticed now that maybe you are talking about Sqllite. Have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946011/sqlite-add-primary-key)

**EDIT2**
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "The value "+yourVariable+" already exists. Please insert a different one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Comment: i create the unique index to prevent user input the same data, so i want to the application throw a message to tell that the data is exist

Comment: I edited my answer although I'm still unsure I understood your question

Comment: the unique index code puts in different file where i want to toast the error to the user. i still cant get your answer, how can i get the condition if i use your solution? e.g if (exist) {toast} else insert the value. How can i put the unique index condition?

Comment: I see. what about if you try to insert and in case of error you show the message?

Comment: yup, thats i want to do, but i dont have any idea how to create that thing, can i do it if i implement unique index?