# sqlite3 if exists alternative

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to run simple query for sqlite which is update a record if not exists.

I could have used `Insert or replace` but `article_tags` table doesn't  have any `primary key` as it is a relational table.

How can I write this query for *`sqlite`* as *`if not exists`* is not supported.
And I don't have idea how to use *CASE* for this **?**

**Table Structure:**

```
articles(id, content)
article_tags(article_id, tag_id)
tag(id, name)
```

**SQLITE Incorrect Syntax Tried**

```
insert into article_tags (article_id, tag_id ) values ( 2,7)
if not exists  (select 1 from article_tags where article_id =2 AND tag_id=7)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this **mysql** if it's about **sqlite3**?

Comment: Why not make a compound unique index and use a plain `insert`? Then when it already exists, you'll get an error, which you can catch.

Comment: Can't you create a multi-column primary key, based on those 2 columns?

Comment: OK, I verified, although [SQLite supports multi-columns primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734689/sqlite-primary-key-on-multiple-columns), it [does not support alter table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/946119/19966) to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct way to do this would be to *add* a primary key to the `article_tags` table, a composite one crossing both columns. That's the normal way to do many-to-many relationship tables.

In other words (pseudo-DDL):

```
create table article_tags (
    article_id  int references articles(id),
    tag_id      int references tag(id),
    primary key (article_id, tag_id)
);
```

That way, insertion of a duplicate pair would fail rather than having to resort to `if not exists`.

Comment: After creating this table, "insert or replace into article_tags" works like it should.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, although I will, as others have also said, suggest that you add some constraints on the table and then simply "try" to insert.

```
insert into article_tags 
  select 2, 7 
  where  not exists ( select * 
                      from   article_tags 
                      where  article_id = 2 
                        and  tag_id     = 7 )
```

Comment: ahh, sorry. I have edited the answer, a little. seems that sqlite3 accepts to have selects even without specifying a table. Even simpler now.