# Convert SQLite ROWID to primary key

Tags: sqlite, rowid

I have a large table without a primary key. Instead, I've been using the built-in `ROWID` as one.

Problem: now I can't `VACUUM` my database, because:

> The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

How can I convert the `ROWID` to an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, preserving existing `ROWIDs` and their behavior (or otherwise get `VACUUM` to not mess up `ROWIDs`)?

Comment: The only way I know of 'for certain' is to recreate the table(s) - but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20561207/2864740 (hacks; YMMV). For the recreate approach SQLite has no problem with manually inserting the PK (or reading the OID) when copying the data.

Comment: @user2864740 The `writable_schema` hack will not work if the new table definition has even the slightest difference in its storage format.