# I get syntax error when I want to reset primary key of sqlite table

Tags: sql, sqlite, auto-increment

I deleted some rows in my database, and I need to reset primary key. I use

```
ALTER TABLE Instructors AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

but I get syntax error.

> Result: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
>   At line 1:
>   ALTER TABLE [Instructors] AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite add Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946011/sqlite-add-primary-key)

Comment: That's not valid sqlite syntax. Where did you get the idea it was?

Comment: Hello Elham, Welcome to SO. I think you are missing the field where you want to add the auto increment