# How Can i fix error Title cannot contain "Error: near "PRIMARY": syntax error"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I made export database from phpmyadmin to file. I want to import database from file sql in DB browser for SQlite. I have

> error: near "PRIMARY": syntax error. I am beginner.

```
CREATE TABLE "uzytkownicy" (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `pass` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `drewno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kamien` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zboze` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dnipremium` int(11) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `uzytkownicy` (`id`, `user`, `pass`, `email`, `drewno`, `kamien`, `zboze`, `dnipremium`) VALUES
(11, 'jonasz', '$2y$10$bS33in2FUkc.vsUpP0ZQl.UyX.cEfhPhGL8h41plJ2awGAhruidXO', 'jonasz@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(12, 'jon', '$2y$10$Mrt6deeNqDWeVXfu4b2myuyqHJZ4iBBBvG9Gp6bT2LMNqK1Y4ubWC', 'jon@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(13, 'jonaszekek', '$2y$10$8cfbUoRdJudHG85WAWvph.fh1sCChrzBLv01tRXBFKxW7kpjT3kVy', 'jonaszekek@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(14, 'jonaszafa', '$2y$10$8PiG8XM/mrs5JEARozVKMu7NXtePoLbAUJ5jnuJjQ1ebVVfsLvoO6', 'jonasz131@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(15, 'joners', '$2y$10$mRn8GrtRXwPu/HtAsqLdN.dvA.W3ZrfkemYbDiwwzHXF8ks4IoO8q', 'jonasz1131@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(16, 'jjaafa', '$2y$10$U/oRS5SJpFKxmp8Yv93moue6nuEV1ZOJYFGKYeaQBHTNkwew4.huu', 'fafafs1131@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(17, 'dadasd', '$2y$10$6Ka7oda8BCxhMUuHzJBaeOcNtLPTZ7Xagu12Qp2n2OqjzdTso48G.', 's1131@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(18, 'agas', '$2y$10$u5bCb1YnRJ5fRETceaeYeO.KT3FnT2.QLyIhPQuXScd7pe74c/SUq', 'dadas1@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(19, 'jdada', '$2y$10$aUCoZ5TVElpUxnJZdOCiXuJPR687pPy8./nMWejtMy9Td743sKde.', 'faf3121@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(20, 'dad', '$2y$10$9P9L.eiVmdIfZ5.iNSuoaeutSqPwmFJF/NYG7UFj.HN45sDu9gWoa', 'fa131@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(21, 'dafas', '$2y$10$0LisKP3Fir5BBRuBXYEoA./mOazARccFg.31QLfHdZbwCqmzJTnei', 'f12131@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14),
(22, 'adsdgs', '$2y$10$P2HvhD.UYP0jhOiIv4UXeOTmYCmWyXZav.6r6p0IAnCQbHRP5BPIi', '876595h@gmail.com', 100, 100, 100, 14);


ALTER TABLE `uzytkownicy`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `uzytkownicy`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=23;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Please add it as one of the tags.  The back-quotes suggest MySQL.  Be aware that there are significant differences between dialects of SQL.  In some DBMS, you might need `…ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (…)…`.  For MySQL, see [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) — version 8 was what came up when I searched Google.

Comment: You can't do that with SQLite. Add your primary key during creating the table.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946011/sqlite-add-primary-key

Answer (score 1):

In sqlite you can NOT add constraint (FK or PK) after creation of table

you have to make a copy of data into another data ,  drop your table and recreate it with all constraint needed and insert back the data.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE uzytkownicy_new (
    [...],
    primary Key (id)
);
INSERT INTO uzytkownicy_new SELECT * FROM uzytkownicy;
DROP TABLE uzytkownicy;
ALTER TABLE uzytkownicy_new RENAME TO uzytkownicy;
COMMIT;
```